# Orbeon Form Data Unique Constraint

Tags: orbeon

When I create a form via form builder, is there a way to define a unique constraint for an instance data/working variable that could prevent the duplicate form data to be created?
   Take RDBMS for example, if we define business key as a unique constraint, duplicate data is not allowed to be inserted into the table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at this time. The closest there is are [singleton forms](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/singleton-form.html).

Comment: I see. Singleton only allow limit form data creation by "user", but we need the singleton control by data constraint e.g. World Cup Application Form shall only be created once by "country id + year". Is this requirement would be supported in the future plan?

Comment: It's a good suggestion but there are no immediate plans, sorry. See also this [FAQ](https://doc.orbeon.com/faq/resources-support.html#when-are-you-going-to-fiximplement-my-favorite-issuefeature). We can enter an RFE though if you wish.